# How do I enable a console of Python in Notepad++?

Tags: python, notepad++

Exactly, I need to execute some functions after programming a script(Like you can do in the IDLE)

Comment: What's wrong with the command line? Can't you run something like `python.exe script.py`?

Comment: Just start up a separate console/terminal, Navigate to where the file is stored and run via `>python.exe <scriptname>`

Comment: Perhaps google could be of assistance.. ([First result](http://pythoncentral.io/execute-python-script-file-shell/))

Comment: If you want to still be in the python shell use `python -i [file]`. It executes the file and drops you into an interactive shell afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Choose the **Run** Menu, and the **Run…** command. Enter the path to your Python executable with the script in parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Run > Run...` in the menu. (Alternatively hit F5). Enter the following as the command to be run:

```
C:\Python26\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Note that depending on your Python version and where it's installed, you may have to change the path to python.exe.

If what you want is to instead run the python interpreter in that directory, what you can do is install NppExec through the Plugin Manager, press F6 to execute (Or go to `Plugins > NppExec > Execute`, and type the following as your command:

```
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
C:\Python26\python.exe
```

Of course, you still have to make sure the python.exe path is correct.

EDIT: To stay in the shell after running your code, do as syntonym commented and add a -i flag to your command.

```
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
C:\Python26\python.exe -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the NppExec Installed and running perfectly, but what I want you to do is to keep writing instructions in the prompt after my code was compiled

Comment: In that case you want to add the -i flag to the program you run.